# How to get Current System IP in C under Windows XP

Tags: c++, c, windows

How can I get current system IP using c under window XP.

Comment: Does window XP allow you to have several network cards installed?

Comment: @pmg: yes. generally one tries to find an interface which is used for default gateway (0.0.0.0). if there is no default gateway configured, then no, there is no "system IP" address.

Comment: @Andrey: Windows is supposedly supports the `getaddrinfo` thus I too consider that as a dup.